# guice assisted injection

Tags: guice

I have a class with a parameterized constructor using AssistedInject as follows:

```
  @Inject
  Portfolio (QuoteDao dao, @Assisted Params params) {...}
```

I create an instance of this class in a command handling servlet:

```
  public class Handler {
    @Inject Strategy strategy;
    Result execute(Action action) {
      Portfolio portfolio = portfolioFactory.create(action.params);
      strategy.execute();
    }
  }
```

My uncertainty begins when I need to obtain a reference to the portfolio in other components of the system. Ideally I'd have it included as part of the constructor, but since it isn't available at injection time this isn't possible.

```
  public class Strategy {
    Portfolio portfolio; <-- how should I get this here?
    @Inject
    public Strategy(QuoteDao dao, ??) {...}
    public execute();
  }
```

The example is somewhat simplified - it's not possible to simply pass the portfolio as part of the execute() call.

I've thought through various solutions, but none seem ideal:

- Inject a PortfolioProvider - but how does the provider get access
  to the portfolio?
- Save the portfolio in the Handler against the logged in user
  (I'm using appengine), then use the logged in user to retrieve in a
  provider - but I would like the system to be able to handle anonymous
  users
- Store the portfolio in a static ThreadLocal, access in a
  provider again - seems very clunky

Would appreciate it very much if someone could help me out here? I'm a newbie with Guice, so hopefully I'm missing something obvious...

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

The `ThreadLocal` might actually be your best bet. Take a look at [SimpleScope](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes) which uses ThreadLocals to make a value injectable for the body of a block of code. If you're already using Guice's servlet integration you'll need to write a `ServletFilter` to enter and exit the `SimpleScope`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jesse - after much deliberation in the end I decided to inject a RequestScoped PortfolioProvider and call a setter to initialize it in the command handler. I can then inject the provider anywhere else in the application and get access to the portfolio. I'm guessing that the request scope uses a threadlocal under the covers somehow anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to have the `Portfolio` be a parameter to the other methods that need it? For instance, instead of `portfolio` being a private member of `Strategy` class, have it be a parameter of execute? It depends upon how many different places you need it I guess.

```
public class Strategy {
    @Inject
    public Strategy(QuoteDao dao, ??) {...}
    public execute(Portfolio portfolio);
}
```

What I've found is that sometimes passing the data objects into strategy classes allows the strategies to be inherently thread-safe because they contain the logic but no mutable data of their own. This allows them to be used more as singletons.

Comment: Hi McKamey, thanks for the answer, but the reason I don't want to do that is because the portfolio needs to be injected in several different application components. Thread safety isn't a concern as (although the servlet is a singleton) the request are executed in requestscope.

Comment: I figured that was probably the case but worth a shot in case it was a fit. Good luck.